# How to extend (or kern) a subtitle to the text width?

Tags: titles, typography, book-design, kerning, extended-characters

I have a subtitle that is almost as large as the text width.  For aesthetical purposes, I would like to strech it a bit so it covers the whole text width, and be more harmonious with the picture below the subtitle.  How can I achieve this trick?

Here's a code that show the subtitle:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{1.5in}{1in}{0.5in}{0.5in}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\definecolor{backgroundcolor}{RGB}{180, 180, 160}
\definecolor{subtitle}{RGB}{240, 240, 200}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{librebaskerville}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand*{\maintitle}{\begingroup

    \pagecolor{backgroundcolor}

    \centering

    \flushleft{
        \textcolor{subtitle}{\Huge\textsf{La théorie classique des champs relativistes}}
    }

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \center
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{figure}

\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

% FRAME AROUND PAGE :
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[line width = 1in,color = white] ($(current page.north west) + (0.25in,0.25in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (0.25in,-0.25in)$);
        \draw[line width = 0.25pt,color = black] ($(current page.north west) + (0.75in,-0.25in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-0.25in,0.25in)$);
        \draw[line width = 1pt,color = white] ($(current page.north west) + (1in,-0.5in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-0.5in,0.5in)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \maintitle
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Preview of what this code is doing:

[image]

All I need here is to extend or stretch the subtitle so it has a lenght equal to the textwidth.  The space to the right should be the same as the space on the left side (which should stay the same).

---

**EDIT:**  I've updated the code above.  Maybe I wasn't clear about how much stretching I wanted.  I certainly don't want the subtitle to be stretched right to the vertical lines on both sides.  The subtitle in flushed left, and there's a nice space between the left line and the beginning of the subtitle.  This should stay fixed.  But then, I need to stretch the right part just a bit, to get a subtitle of the same size as the picture below it.

Answer (score 4):

I'd avoid this.

Anyway, here's how you can do it. Note that accented characters and possible ligatures have to be braced.

I made some adjustments:

1. `anysize` is much less powerful than `geometry` and has not been maintained in 26 years;
2. the `here` package is obsolete; use `float` instead, but *never* use `[H]`;
3. the `minipage` doesn't seem needed, particularly with width `2\textwidth`;
4. to set something larger than the text width, use `\makebox`;
5. I added some space at either size so the text doesn't touch the frame lines.

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[inner=1.5in,outer=1in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed with recent versions of LaTeX
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\definecolor{backgroundcolor}{RGB}{180, 180, 160}
\definecolor{subtitle}{RGB}{240, 240, 200}

\usepackage{lmodern} % for sans serif
\usepackage{librebaskerville}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\expandto}{mm}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } { #2 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { \cham_expand_word:n { ##1 } }
  \leavevmode
  \hbox_to_wd:nn { #1 }
   {
    \hspace{3pt}
    \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { \hspace{0.33333em plus 1fil} }
    \hspace{3pt}
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \cham_expand_word:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { } { #1 }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \hspace{0pt plus 0.6fil} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*{\maintitle}{%
  \begingroup
  \pagecolor{backgroundcolor}
  \centering
  \makebox[\textwidth]{%
    \color{subtitle}\Huge\sffamily
    \expandto{\textwidth+1in}{La th{é}orie classique des champs relativistes}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

% FRAME AROUND PAGE :
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[line width = 1in,color = white] ($(current page.north west) + (0.25in,0.25in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (0.25in,-0.25in)$);
  \draw[line width = 0.25pt,color = black] ($(current page.north west) + (0.75in,-0.25in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-0.25in,0.25in)$);
  \draw[line width = 1pt,color = white] ($(current page.north west) + (1in,-0.5in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-0.5in,0.5in)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

    \maintitle

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Look at the picture and see why I started with ‘I'd avoid this’. ;-)

If the title should use the text width:

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[inner=1.5in,outer=1in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed with recent versions of LaTeX
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\definecolor{backgroundcolor}{RGB}{180, 180, 160}
\definecolor{subtitle}{RGB}{240, 240, 200}

\usepackage{lmodern} % for sans serif
\usepackage{librebaskerville}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\expandto}{O{0pt}mm}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } { #3 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { \cham_expand_word:n { ##1 } }
  \leavevmode
  \hbox_to_wd:nn { #2 }
   {
    \hspace{#1}
    \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { \hspace{0.33333em plus 1fil} }
    \hspace{#1}
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \cham_expand_word:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { } { #1 }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \hspace{0pt plus 0.6fil} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*{\maintitle}{%
  \begingroup
  \pagecolor{backgroundcolor}
  \centering
  \makebox[\textwidth]{%
    \color{subtitle}\Huge\sffamily
    \expandto{\textwidth}{La th{é}orie classique des champs relativistes}%
  }\\
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

% FRAME AROUND PAGE :
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[line width = 1in,color = white] ($(current page.north west) + (0.25in,0.25in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (0.25in,-0.25in)$);
  \draw[line width = 0.25pt,color = black] ($(current page.north west) + (0.75in,-0.25in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-0.25in,0.25in)$);
  \draw[line width = 1pt,color = white] ($(current page.north west) + (1in,-0.5in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-0.5in,0.5in)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

    \maintitle

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

About your edit:

- `\flushleft` is not a user level command and it takes *no* argument;
- there is no need to use `figure` around an image.

I transformed the padding on either side into an optional argument to `\expandto` just in case you need it elsewhere.

Comment: egreg, you stretched too much the subtitle. I need to keep the same space as before on the left side, and stretch the line to the right so the right space is the same as on the left side, without using a centering command. The reason is that I use a large picture below the subtitle. The picture as a width = \textwidth.

Comment: egreg, I updated my question and the code example.

Comment: @Cham I added the code.